# cocoa-How to use tableViewSelectionDidChange:?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, delegates, nstableview

I have a `NSTableview` in my `view` and I want to do some other thing when the user select a particular `row`. I tried `tableViewSelectionDidChange` method but it seemed not working.

```
-(void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    NSInteger row = [self.InfoTable selectedRow];

    if (row == -1) {
        return;
    }else{
        self.NumberInputTextField.stringValue = studentsInTable[row][0];
        self.NameInputTextField.stringValue = studentsInTable[row][1];
        self.ClassnumberInputTextField.stringValue = studentsInTable[row][1];
    }
}
```

and I have

```
@interface ViewController : NSViewController <NSTableViewDelegate,NSTableViewDataSource>
```

and

```
self.InfoTable.dataSource = self;
self.InfoTable.dataSource = self;
```

Also, I've googled but haven't found a useful answer.
Can any one give me a hint on it?

Answer (score 1):

`- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)aNotification` is delegate method but you are only setting dataSource to self.

```
[self.InfoTable setDelegate:self];
```

Comment: Thanks. I've fixed the problem and it works pretty well!

Answer (score 1):

If you have a cell-based or view-based `NSTableView` then nothing as such is required. Just make sure the tableView's `delegate` is set to the controller class, and you implement them.

Or you can do the above with codes:

```
self.InfoTable.dataSource = self;
self.InfoTable.delegate = self; //Note you used dataSource twice
```

[image]

And make sure you implement these methods if you are not doing binding to load the `tableView`.

```
- (void)tableViewSelectionDidChange:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"Your seleceted a row...");
}

- (NSInteger)numberOfRowsInTableView:(NSTableView *)tableView {
    return [self.anArray count];
}

- (id) tableView:(NSTableView *)TableView
objectValueForTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)tableColumn
             row:(int)row {

    return self.anArray[row];
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Actually I didn't even noticed that I used datasource twice. Now the method is working!